# Magento2.3.4 Class 'Mage' not found

Tags: magento2.3

I just moved a Magento 2.3.4 website to a new server and now I am getting an error that says

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'Mage' not found in /var/www/index.php:59
```

The index.php file looks like the below (which works on another machine)

```
try {
   require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) 
{
echo <<<HTML
 <div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
   <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
       <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
       Autoload error</h3>
   </div>
   <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
 </div>
HTML;
exit(1);
}

//$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
//$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
//$bootstrap->run($app);

switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
case 'stagesite.domaina.com':
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'ydsite';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
break;
case 'stagesite.domainb.com':
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'default';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
break;
default:
 Mage::run();
 break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use below code in **default** section for **Magento 2**

```
default: 
    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
    $bootstrap->run($app);
    break;
```

Hope this will help you!